# Point and use a subdomain in GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a primary domain `www.example.com` setup in Route 53 on AWS.

I want to point `subdomain1.example.com` to Google Cloud, specifically to an instance group running in Google Compute Engine.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow because it is not about programming.  In the future similar questions should be asked elsewhere.  Questions about managing your server can be asked at [sf] and questions about managing your website can be asked at [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, and this is a good design practice called nameservice delegation.  The best approach is to delegate an entire subdomain for GCP, so let's use the domain example.com and gcp.example.com as the domain and subdomain.

This way Google will manage DNS for you rather than you updating A & CNAME records in route53 manually.

Overall this will take these steps (1) creating the `gcp.example.com` zone in GCP (2) obtaining the NS records for `gcp.example.com` (3) delegating `NS` for `gcp.example.com` to Google Cloud NS and then (4) Create the resource-level records (e.g. for a VM or appengine app) in GCP Cloud DNS.

**(1) Creating the Zone in GCP**

This can be done in the console under `Network Services -> Cloud DNS` or the cloud shell. I favor the shell.

```
$ gcloud dns managed-zones create gcp-example --description="GCP Example Zone" \
      --dns-name="gcp.example.com"
```

**(2) Obtain the NS Records for the new Zone**

Below is an example -- copy the ones specific to your NS

```
gcloud dns managed-zones describe gcp-example |grep -A5 nameServers
nameServers:
- ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com.
- ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com.
```

**(3) Add the delegate NS record in AWS**

create update.json (make sure the value records are correct):

```
{
            "Comment": "CREATE/DELETE/UPSERT a record ",
            "Changes": [{
            "Action": "CREATE",
                        "ResourceRecordSet": {
                                    "Name": "gcp.example.com",
                                    "Type": "NS",
                                    "TTL": 300,
                                 "ResourceRecords": [ {"Value" : "ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com."}, {"Value": "ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com."},
                                     {"Value" : "ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com."}, {"Value": "ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com."}]
}}]
}
```

```
HOSTED_ZONE_ID=XXXXXX
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id=${HOSTED_ZONE_ID} --change-batch=file://./update.json
{
    "ChangeInfo": {
        "Status": "PENDING",
        "Comment": "CREATE/DELETE/UPSERT a record ",
        "SubmittedAt": "2019-02-27T23:43:35.327Z",
        "Id": "/change/XXXXXX"
    }
}
```

**(4) In GCP Cloud DNS, create all of your gcp resource records under `gcp.example.com`**

At this point, you can manage all of your GCP dns within GCP Cloud DNS.  Go ahead and create `vm1.gcp.example.com` or `appengine1.gcp.example.com`

Comment: This is such a great answer, I never even thought about the idea of creating a second level domain (gcp.example.com) - genius! By doing this I can create a single Google Cloud SSL managed certificate for this level domain and this will also take care of any subdomains such as a.gcp.example.com or b.gcp.example.com?

Comment: Yes exactly.  NS delegation is key to managing cross-cloud resources e.g. azc.example.com (for azure cloud), gcp.example.com etc.  

Once delegated, Cloud DNS will auto-manage all naming for you, as well as certificates and domain validation.  

This saves you tons of headaches and work down the road.

My team does a lot of cross-cloud deployments feel free to ping me if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks a tonne, really helpful going forward! I couldn't see the option to ping you but I have one more question related. Say I have several APIs being serviced via different sub domains in this setup, is it a good idea to have a single Load Balancer for all of them as I can setup the URL map rules to forward the requests to the appropriate service depending on the URL. So is there a good reason to have more than one load balancer instead?

Comment: The simple answer is yes just use a single LB with routing rules.  The main reasons to use multiple LBs would be (a) to host the 2nd LB in another zone for HA and (b) if you need more than 10 SSL certs on the LB .   Since both cases are easy to do without downtime, I would start with a single LB

Comment: In the DNS records on GCP, do I need to explicitly map each subdomain to the the load balancer's static ip. E.g. example.com currently points to <LOAD_BALANCER_STATIC_IP>, for `foo.example.com` do I have to also point to <LOAD_BALANCER_STATIC_IP> before I configure the Host and path rules in the load balancer itself?

Comment: I don't believe the order in which you do it matters, but yes you'll need one of these for each "virtualhost" on the load balancer (a) a routing table entry, and (b) a cloud DNS entry for that hostname.  I also recommend adding either a wildcard (or SAN) cert or multiple certs, one each per hostname

Comment: That's great, Google Cloud Managed SSL certificates do not support wildcards unfortunately but nonetheless I can create one for each for now. Thanks!